# Stop Apache Tomcat using JMX

Tags: java, tomcat7, jmx, tomcat8

Is there any way to stop Apache Tomcat using Java and JMX?

I suppose that there is a a managed bean which can be used for this?

Comment: may be you can use Runtime class to execute command for stopping Tomcat, the way you would do from command line.

Comment: This would seem like a gaping security hole to me.

Comment: Can you show me some Java code example please?

Comment: What is the purpose of shutting down Tomcat? I have a Java standalone application that manages locally a tomcat daemon using ant tasks, [following official Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html), if you are interested I can give you samplecode.

Comment: I just want to have this functionality. Can you show me some example with Java and JMX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By its own the Tomcat does not come with the ability to shutdown operation run from the `JMX`, basically it is not secure !!! But if you really need it you need to create your own `ShutdownMBean`. It is very easy and straight forward process of creating the `MBean` and registering it at application deploy.
Lets first create the `ShutdownMBean` whch will have name and will expose a single `doShutdown()` operation.

```
public interface ShutdownMBean {
    void doShutdown();
    String getName();
}
```

The implementation is easy as well, just send `SHUTDOWN` signal to default shutdown port of Tomcat.

```
public class Shutdown implements ShutdownMBean{

    @Override
    public void doShutdown() {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8005);
            clientSocket.getOutputStream().write("SHUTDOWN".getBytes());
            clientSocket.getOutputStream().close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Shutdown JMX Hook";
    }

}
```

And at the end just register the `ShutdownMBean` after context initialization (I assume you are using Tomcat 7+):

```
@WebListener
public class ShutdownListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try {
            ShutdownMBean shutdownMBean = new Shutdown();
            MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            ObjectName name = new ObjectName("com.example:type=Shutdown");
            server.registerMBean(shutdownMBean, name);
        } catch (InstanceAlreadyExistsException | MBeanRegistrationException | NotCompliantMBeanException | MalformedObjectNameException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Thats it, just deploy your app, connect to your Tomcat using `JConsole` and you will find `doShutdown` operation under `com.example` group